# MYSQL Simple Moving Average Calculation

Tags: mysql, performance, moving-average

The following MySql update state seems to take an excessive amount of time to execute for the recordset provided (~5000 records). The update statement below takes on average 12 seconds to execute. I currently plan to run this calculation for 5 different periods and about 500 different stock symbols. This translates into 12secs * 5 calculations * 500 symbols = 30,000 seconds or 8..33 hrs.

**Update Statement:**

```
UPDATE tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL JOIN 
(SELECT t1.Sequence,
   (
    SELECT AVG(t2.Close)
        FROM tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL AS t2
        WHERE (t1.Sequence - t2.Sequence)BETWEEN 0 AND 7
    )AS "8SMA" 
FROM tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL AS t1 
ORDER BY t1.Sequence) AS ma_query 
ON tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL.Sequence = ma_query.Sequence  
SET tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL.8MA_Price = ma_query.8SMA
```

**Table Design:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL` (
  `Symbol` char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TradeDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `Sequence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Close` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `200MA_Price` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `100MA_Price` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `50MA_Price` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `20MA_Price` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `8MA_Price` decimal(18,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `50_200_Cross` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Symbol`,`Sequence`),
  KEY `idxSequnce` (`Sequence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Any help on sppeding up the process would be greatly appreciated.

**Output of Select Explain:**

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key                 key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             t1      index   NULL            idxSymbol_Sequnce   11      NULL    5205    Using index; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  t2      ALL     NULL            NULL                NULL    NULL    5271    Using where
```

Comment: Please include the output of 'desc' - esp for the inner part (select) of the query

Comment: Actualy, you have three nested queries, only one with condition (which can not be used for optimisation). So, mysql has to look through 5000**3 rows (125 * 10**9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a little better:

```
update tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL
join (
  select t1.sequence as sequence, avg(t2.close) as av
  from tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL t1
  join tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL t2
  on t2.sequence BETWEEN t1.sequence-7 AND t1.sequence
  group by t1.sequence
) t1 on tblStockDataMovingAverages_AAPL.sequence = t1.sequence
set 8MA_Price = t1.av
```

With regard to my `BETWEEN` statement: `field1 OPERATOR expression(field2)` is easier to optimise than `expression(field1, field2) OPERATOR expression` in the `ON` condition. I think this holds for `BETWEEN`.

It looks like the `ORDER BY` in your query is unnecessary and removing it might speed your query up a ton.

If any of the stock symbols appear in the same table, stick all these into a single update query (different periods won't work though), this would likely be way faster than running it for each.

As already suggested, adding an index to `Close` may help.

Answer (score 1):

you can optimize it slightly by adding index to `Close` field. AVG function have to be more effective. Please share dump of your dataset to see it more close.